# change the outputted data depending on value if ($tv == '0') {echo 'user' }

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the output of a variable from 0 to display user or from 1 to display superuser,

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    $tv = nl2br($row['type']);

    if ($tv == '0') {
        $tv = 'user';
    } elseif ($tv == '3') {
        $tv = 'superuser';                              
    } else {
        $tv = 'N/A';
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td>" . nl2br( $row['name'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . nl2br( $row['email']) . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $tv . "</td>";  
            echo "</tr>";  
    } 
?>
```

i know I'm validating the data before i do the mysql_fetch_array and that should do it after, but i wasn't able to put the if statement in the echo

any help pls ?

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* function library. It's deprecated and you should be using mysqli

Comment: @Zarathuztra if you can focus on the question, i need to use depreciating libraries

Comment: I can assure you you don't. I'm trying to understand your question exactly. One issue I see is that you're trying to access the $row array before it even exists

Comment: @Zarathuztra the concept of the project is to use depreciating mysql_* library, would you like me to send you the email of my instructor?

Comment: Quite frankly, your instructor is wrong. I don't need to see anything to know that. Outside that, what is the exact issue you're seeing? I just gave one possible cause of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access $row before it is set, you can alter your echo line for $row['type'] like this:

```
if ($row['type'] == 0) { echo 'user'; } else if ($row['type'] == 1) { echo 'superuser';} else {echo 'NA'; }
```

---

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td>" . nl2br( $row['name'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . nl2br( $row['email']) . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>"; if ($row['type'] == 0) { echo 'user'; } else if ($row['type'] == 1) { echo 'superuser';} else {echo 'NA'; } echo "</td>";  
            echo "</tr>";  
    } 

?>
```

---

I'm sure you have a reason for using nl2br, but I totally don't get it.

As @Zarathuztra has mentionend, please change to mysqli_ or PDO, mysql_ is not the way to go as it is deprecated